Uncovering the Structure of a Localization of a Ring Given the Universal Property
Consider the universal property of ring localization:
Let $R$ be a commutative right with unity with a multiplicative subset $S$. Let $S^{-1}R$ denote the localization of $R$ by $S$. Then, $\phi:R \to S^{-1}R$ has the universal property that given any ring homomorphism $\varphi:R \to A$ such that $\varphi(s)$ is a unit for any $s \in S$, there exists a unique $\psi:S^{-1}R \to A$ wherein $\varphi=\psi \circ \phi$.
Given the general construction of $S^{-1}R$ wherein we construct fractions $r/s$ for $r \in R$ and $s \in S$, one can see how the universal property is derived. Namely, $\phi(r)=r/1$ for $r \in R$, and we define $\psi(r/s)=\varphi(s)^{-1}\varphi(r)$.
My question is how do we derive useful information about the local ring $S^{-1}R$ given the universal property? I'm reading Vakil's The Rising Sea, and in introducing universal properties, one exercise is to prove the existence of $S^{-1}R$ using the universal property. If you know about ring localization already, you already know how to construct $S^{-1}R$, and so the problem is tantamount to reconstructing the local ring and showing it satisfies the universal property.
As I understand it, universal properties are supposed to encode the information about the object it is describing. So, if one were to know nothing of localization and were instead handed the universal property of ring localization, how would one go about uncovering the data/ structure of the localization of $R$ by $S$?

Just a quick comment, not at all entirely answering: sure, of course, there is no (elementary) universal way to "construct" (as a way of proving existence?) universal objects. Nevertheless, perhaps less elementarily, once can prove things about universal objects (a.k.a. representable functors...) by using a variety of "test objects" to fit into the universal property's diagram. Sure, that doesn't describe any sort of guaranteed procedure, either, but ... definitely "in-principle" ... it does suffice to tell about the thing.

Note: "local ring" is usually a term used to describe a (commutative unital) ring with a unique maximal ideal. You seem to be asking about localizations in general, not about "local rings" in particular.

The universal property is the most important tool to work with localizations. Namely, it allows you to construct homomorphism from them, which is useful to

prove compatibility results, such as $T^{-1} (S^{-1} R) \cong T^{-1} R$ for $S \subseteq T \subseteq R$, or $R \otimes S^{-1} R' \cong S^{-1} (R \otimes R')$,
identify localizations, for example $(R \times S)_{(1,0)} \cong R$.

Even though you could in theory do all this by fiddling around with elements, this takes much more effort.
Generally speaking, you need to distinguish between a ring (or more generally, an object of a concrete category) and its underlying set. This  distinction is usually a bit hard to see since most people write $R$ for the underlying set of a ring $R$, even though these objects are not the same (one is a set, the other is a ring, thus has extra structure). One may write $|R|$ for the underlying set of a ring $R$, for example.
The universal property of $S^{-1} R$ pins it down as a ring. What you asking, though, seems to be how we find a description of the underlying set $|S^{-1} R|$. This can indeed be derived from the universal property:

Equality of elements in localization via universal property
Elements in a localization - category theoretic approach

See in particular the great answer by D.-C. Cisinski.

A comment first. It is a little too much of a gloss to say that the universal property "encodes" the information about the object it is describing, if by that you mean that it provides you enough information to "completely describe" the object.
While it is true that the universal property determines the object up to unique canonical isomorphism, if it exists, this may be a far cry from allowing you to explicitly describe the object.
For example, it is easy to state the universal property of the free Burnside group of rank $k$ and exponent $5$: it a group $B_5(k)$, together with a function $u\colon\{x_1,\ldots,x_k\}\to B_5(k)$, such that for any group $G$ of exponent $5$ and any set map $v\colon\{x_1,\ldots,x_k\}$, there exists a unique group homomorphism $\phi\colon B_5(k)\to G$ such that $v=\phi u$. I can even tell you that $B_5(k) = F(k)/N$, where $F(k)$ is the free group of rank $k$ and $N$ is the subgroup generated by the set $\{w^5\mid w\in F(k)\}$. However, nobody knows whether $B_5(k)$ is even finite or infinite for large $k$. So while the universal property "encodes" the structure of this group, this encoding has not proven to be enough to actually describe the group in any kind of useful manner.
So in general it is not a given that describing an object by a universal property, even if you can prove such an object will definitely exist, will allow you to describe such an object in a useful and clear manner. That's why for most universal objects we often want, in addition to the universal property description, an actual construction or reification of that object that we can get our hands on.
That said, I think your question lies more along the lines of the discussion in Section 4.8 of George Bergman's An Invitation to General Algebra and Universal Constructions:

The philosophy of how to construct objects with properties of either kind
is in broad outline the same: Figure out as much information as possible
about an arbitrary object (not assumed universal) with the given sort of "additional structure", and see whether that information can itself be considered as a description of an object. If it can, this object will in general turn out to be universal for the given structure! In the case of "left universal" constructions (free groups, coproducts, etc.), this "information" means answers to the question, "What elements do we know exist, and what equalities must hold among them?" (cf. Remark 3.2.13). In the right universal case, on the other hand, the corresponding question is, "Given an element of our object, what data can one describe about it in terms of the additional structure?"

So, let us assume we have a commutative ring $R$ with unity $1$, a submonoid $S$ of the multiplicative structure of $R$, and we with to define a universal pair $(S^{-1}R,\phi)$ consisting of a commutative ring $S^{-1}R$ with unity and a unital ring homomorphism $\phi\colon R\to S^{-1}R$, such that $\phi(s)$ is a unit in $S^{-1}R$ and universal among all such pairs. What can we say about $S^{-1}R$?
Well, it certainly must contain elements $\phi(r)$ for each $r$ in $R$; it must also contain elements $\phi(s)^{-1}$ for each $s\in S$. We can consider formal ring expressions on the set $R\sqcup S^{-1}$, where $S^{-1}$ is the set for formal symbols $\{s^{-1}\mid s\in S\}$; identify $\phi(r)$ with the symbol $r$, and write $\phi(s)^{-1}$ as $s^{-1}$; then using commutativity of products, associativity, the multiplication rules in $R$, the fact that if $s$ and $s'$ are invertible then it must be the case that $(ss')^{-1}=s^{-1}(s')^{-1}$, etc., we can rewrite any such expression to an expression of the form
$$s_1^{-1}r_1 + s_2^{-1}r_2 + \cdots + s_mr_m$$
for some $s_1,\ldots,s_m\in S$, $r_1,\ldots,r_m\in R$, and $m\geq 0$. Moreover, it must be the case that $s^{-1}r$ is equal to $(ss')^{-1}(rs')$, using commutativity.
Using distributivity, we can ensure that $s^{-1}r + s^{-1}r' = s^{-1}(r+r')$. That means that the expression above can be rewritten as a single $s^{-1}r$, by replacing $(s_i)^{-1}r_i$ with $$(s_1\cdots s_m)^{-1}(s_1\cdots s_{i-1}r_is_{i+1}\cdots s_m)$$
and then adding. So in fact, we have that the image of $\phi(R)$ together with $S^{-1}$ will generate elements that can be written as $s^{-1}r$.
But these expressions are not unique, as already noted. Are there other equalities that we can ensure besudes $s^{-1}r = (ss')^{-1}(rs')$?
If $s^{-1}r=(s')^{-1}r'$, then multiplying through by $ss'$ we get $rs' = r's$, which would hold in $R$. Conversely, if $rs' = r's$, then multiplying by $(ss')^{-1}$ we obtain $s^{-1}r = (s')^{-1}r'$, which must hold in this new universal ring. Thinking about this we might also note that
if there exists $u\in S$ such that $rs'u = tsu$ then it must be the case that $s^{-1}r = (s')^{-1}t$, by going through $(su)^{-1}(ru) = (s'u)^{-1}(tu)$.
The basic rules of commutative rings will tell us that $(s^{-1}r)((s')^{-1}r')$ should equal $(ss')^{-1}(rr')$. And we already saw that we add them by using
$$s^{-1}r + (s')^{-1}r' = (ss')^{-1}(rs') + (ss')^{-1}(r's) = (ss')^{-1}(rs'+r's).$$
At this point, we have probably exhausted the things we know must happen in $S^{-1}R$. So now the question is: do these elements, with these addition and multiplication rules, with that equivalence among them (namely, $s^{-1}r = (s')^{-1}r'$ if and only if there exists $u\in S$ such that $rs'u = r'su$) already describe a ring with unity, and a morphism $\phi\colon R\to S^{-1}R$? It is not hard to verify that they do, and that it has the desired universal property... so this "is" the ring described by the universal property.

Notice that you have the assumption that understanding an object also requires understanding its underlying set. From a pure categorical point of view, understanding an object via its morphisms to other objects is sufficient. The "underlying set functor" does not belong to the category itself and requires a different analysis. This POV is in particular important when dealing with more abstract objects. Say you want to understand the quotient sheaf of a subsheaf. You don't understand it by writing down the sections, which are very complicated. You understand it by the universal property.

@MartinBrandenburg I agree. Though here, as in Bergman's book, we are dealing with algebraic structures (in the sense of universal algebra) and we want to actually study their structure as such rings/groups/modules/etc. And it is not merely the "underlying set" (not sure where you get that insinuation). In the relatively free Burnside group example, knowing whether it is finite or not is the whole point of the object.

Finite group := group whose underlying set is finite. Maybe you get my point now

@MartinBrandenburg I got your point from the start. You seem to have missed mine. No one is saying either that "understanding" an object requires understanding the underlying set, nor that one should look at underlying sets always, a position you seem to claim I am espousing. For Burnside, you study the universal object because you want to determine finiteness; not the other way around (as your point tries to assert). The excursion in that paragraph is to disabuse of the notion that the universal property alone allows a description, so one need not attempt it as first step (cont)

(cont) And if what you want is to actually construct the object for some reason (or to prove existence) how do you go about it? This is a heuristic for that, not a prescription for how to understand universal objects. So your point happens to be neither here not there.
